# Transform 8bpp image into 24bpp and preserve color

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I have an 8bpp image with a custom palete that holds a colored picture. [image]

Now, I'm trying to convert it to `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` format picture. I'm using direct pixels access using the code from here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

and the usage is

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile("T:\\500-blue-orig.png");
LockBitmap lbmpSrc = new LockBitmap(bmp);
Bitmap dst = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
LockBitmap lbmpDst = new LockBitmap(dst);

lbmpSrc.LockBits();
lbmpDst.LockBits();

dst.Palette = bmp.Palette;
for (int y = 0; y < lbmpSrc.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < lbmpSrc.Width; x++)
    {
        Color c = lbmpSrc.GetPixel(x, y);

        lbmpDst.SetPixel(x, y, c);
    }
}

lbmpDst.UnlockBits();
lbmpSrc.UnlockBits();

dst.Save("T:\\x.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

However the ending result is a grayscale image even though I do copy the original palette.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get a `24bpp` colored image from a `8bpp` picture which actually has colors?

Comment: Why not just create a new bitmap based on the old one with new format, or draw the bitmap onto a new one? Much faster and less code.

Comment: I do use that code, look carefully, I'm using GetPixel from LockBitmap not Bitmap. And I cannot bitmap copying as this is part of a much more complex image manipulation method.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, noticed that. But using that class isn't much better since there's still conversions to Color and method calls and data copying. Could do much faster. But can't see anything wrong with the code immediately.

Comment: Oh, wait. The code you use assumes 8bit images are always grayscale. It doesn't handle palettes. That's the reason.

Comment: but then how come the original image has colors? How would I use the palette to get the actual color?

Comment: Just use GetPixel from Bitmap and don't use the LockBitmap class? Or beforehand copy the image into a 32bpp image and then handle it

Comment: I can't, in my initial problem I do have an array of pixels, just like in this sample. I need t operate with arrays.

Comment: But you're not using arrays in this code. What is the actual code then if it's not like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a manual approach using unmanaged code - local benchmark shows it to be 99.7% faster than the ignorant (`Bitmap.GetPixel` > `Bitmap.SetPixel`) approach.

Basically, we use the `LockBits` pointer and assign bytes one by one based on the color palette.

```
static unsafe void To24Bpp(Bitmap source, Bitmap dest)
{
    var sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    var destData = dest.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, dest.Width, dest.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var paletteBytes = source.Palette.Entries.Select(ColorToUintRgbLeftAligned).ToArray();
    var current = (byte*) sourceData.Scan0.ToPointer();
    var lastPtr = (byte*) (sourceData.Scan0 + sourceData.Width*sourceData.Height).ToPointer();
    var targetPtr = (byte*) destData.Scan0;
    while (current <= lastPtr)
    {
        var value = paletteBytes[*current++];
        targetPtr[0] = (byte) (value >> 24);
        targetPtr[1] = (byte) (value >> 16);
        targetPtr[2] = (byte) (value >> 8);
        targetPtr += 3;
    }

    source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
    dest.UnlockBits(destData);
}

static uint ColorToUintRgbLeftAligned(Color color)
{
    return ((uint) color.B << 24) + ((uint) color.G << 16) + ((uint) color.R << 8);
}
```

The code could be improved to write 4 bytes at a time from the color pallette, reducing the amount of random memory access. My local benchmark showed the performance of this improved by a further 25%. Note the difference in building the `uint` color bytes - the alignment of bytes in a `uint` was opposite of what I expected.

```
private static unsafe void To24BppUintAssignment(Bitmap source, Bitmap dest)
{
    var sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    var destData = dest.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, dest.Width, dest.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    uint[] paletteBytes = source.Palette.Entries.Select(ColorToUintRgbRightAligned).ToArray();
    var current = (byte*)sourceData.Scan0.ToPointer();
    var lastPtr = (byte*)(sourceData.Scan0 + sourceData.Width * sourceData.Height).ToPointer();
    var targetPtr = (byte*) destData.Scan0;
    while (current < lastPtr)
    {
        var targetAsUint = ((uint*) targetPtr);
        targetAsUint[0] = paletteBytes[*current++];
        targetPtr += 3;
    }
    uint finalValue = paletteBytes[*current];
    targetPtr[0] = (byte)(finalValue >> 24);
    targetPtr[1] = (byte)(finalValue >> 16);
    targetPtr[2] = (byte)(finalValue >> 8);
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
    dest.UnlockBits(destData);
    }
    private static uint ColorToUintRgbRightAligned(Color color)
    {
        return ((uint)color.B) + ((uint)color.G << 8) + ((uint)color.R << 16);
    }
```

I didn't create the bitmap in the method for benchmarking purposes, it should be called as such:

```
static Bitmap To24Bpp(Bitmap source)
{
    var dest = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    To24BppUintAssignment(source, dest);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I locate the right color in a palette in case I have a 24bpp picture?

Comment: The Palette has a color per entry, you'd have to do a reverse lookup if you have a Color.

Answer (score 1):

The `LockBitmap` class you are using doesn't care about palette, it assumes 8bpp images are always grayscale and will return only grays.

Also the class is far from fast since it copies bitmap data to another array and back, creates `Color` when not necessarily needed etc. If you really want performance you will do the handling yourself.

You have two choices:

- use `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` from `Bitmap` directly. It will work as it should.
- copy the 8bpp palette image into a 32/24bpp image first, then use that class for processing

Comment: ok, I can try the second option. But out of curiosity, how would I implement a GetPixel that does care about palette?

Comment: 8-bit images aren't considered grayscale at all. In fact, once you're on byte level, they aren't 'considered' anything; they're just bytes. And those bytes refer to indices on the image's colour palette.

Comment: @Nyerguds If you bothered to read the code being used it specifically assumes the 8bpp values are grayscale since it returns colors with R, G and B set to the value stored. It ignores the palette as I said.

Comment: So that just reduces the matter to "some external code I used is buggy". I see.

Comment: @Nyerguds Not buggy at all, just functions differently as assumed. Just like my answer states. And not “some external code”, “this external code.”

Answer (score 0):

People here seem to all be ridiculously overcomplicating matters. Converting an 8BPP image to 24BPP or 32BPP doesn't need any special code.

The only thing that's difficult about 8BPP images is manipulating *them*, and, you don't need to do that at all; your end result *isn't* one of these problematic 8BPP images.

You can do it in less than five lines:

```
public static Bitmap PaintOn32bpp(Image image)
{
    Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bp))
        gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bp.Width, bp.Height));
    return bp;
}
```

This will work with any image, regardless of its colour format.